# SQL syntax - division and ceiling functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate how many packs of sweats a kid needs based on the amount of individual sweets required. I am trying to figure out the SQL syntax to do this.

I have used ceiling with divide but still not working

```
select CEILING(NoOfSweets / SweetsPerPack) AS NoOfPacks
```

Scenarios:

```
NoOfSweets   SweetsPerPack   RequiredOutCome   NoOfPacks
--------------------------------------------------------
10               10             1                 1
 5               10             1                 0
20               10             2                 2
 8               10             1                 0      
 7                5             2                 1
```

Comment: Define "not working". What happens when you run that code? Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are integers, then SQL Server does integer division.  So, `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  I find that the simplest way to get a number with decimal points is to multiply by `1.0`:

```
CEILING(NoOfSweets * 1.0 / SweetsPerPack)
```